How does Quake 1 access video memory in software mode?
I have WinQuake.exe game file which I compiled myself from source.
In software mode (without DirectX/OpenGL), what function is used to access video memory?
I know, for example, the DrawDibDraw WinAPI function; but I didn't find it in the code.

Guess: direct video RAM access for speed. But since you compiled it from source, why don't you edit your question and put in a link to the source, so we can look?

There is too much code to post here, and I did not find the place where direct access to video memory is used. But what if the file is called WinQuake.exe, and that is, used under Windows, and how can direct access to video memory be used under Windows?

Run it under a profiler and see where the CPU spends its time.

You can see https://fabiensanglard.net/quakeSource/quakeSourceRendition.php for some looks at rendering in quake

@black4 "How can an exe file have access to video memory?" By using a library (as the below answer states) that probably registers a driver, which then gives the main program direct access. You said you compiled it from source, didn't it reference the library? And all you need is to post a link, not the code itself. I am too lazy to start a Google spree for every question asked here, sorry for my directness.

Guess what it might be and then giving up because you can't validate that particular answer is not a particularly fruitful way to understand someone else's code.  And unfortunately, understanding someone else's code is often a large part of programming,

VtC - another SO question, not RC.

When running in software mode, Quake uses SciTech's MGL.
The screen buffer is locked using VID_LockBuffer which calls MGL_beginDirectAccess:
void VID_LockBuffer (void)
{
    ...

    MGL_beginDirectAccess();

    if (memdc)
    {
        // Update surface pointer for linear access modes
        vid.buffer = vid.conbuffer = vid.direct = memdc->surface;
        vid.rowbytes = vid.conrowbytes = memdc->mi.bytesPerLine;
    }
    else if (mgldc)
    {
        // Update surface pointer for linear access modes
        vid.buffer = vid.conbuffer = vid.direct = mgldc->surface;
        vid.rowbytes = vid.conrowbytes = mgldc->mi.bytesPerLine;
    }

    ...
}

Screen state is then available through variable vid:
viddef_t    vid;                // global video state

Whose definition is in vid.h:
typedef struct
{
    pixel_t         *buffer;        // invisible buffer
    pixel_t         *colormap;      // 256 * VID_GRADES size
    unsigned short  *colormap16;    // 256 * VID_GRADES size
    int             fullbright;     // index of first fullbright color
    unsigned        rowbytes;   // may be > width if displayed in a window
    unsigned        width;      
    unsigned        height;
    float           aspect;     // width / height -- < 0 is taller than wide
    int             numpages;
    int             recalc_refdef;  // if true, recalc vid-based stuff
    pixel_t         *conbuffer;
    int             conrowbytes;
    unsigned        conwidth;
    unsigned        conheight;
    int             maxwarpwidth;
    int             maxwarpheight;
    pixel_t         *direct;        // direct drawing to framebuffer, if not
                                    //  NULL
} viddef_t;

For instance, the update screen method SCR_UpdateScreen:
void SCR_UpdateScreen (void)
{
    ...

    D_DisableBackBufferAccess ();   // for adapters that can't stay mapped in
                                    //  for linear writes all the time

    VID_LockBuffer ();

    V_RenderView ();

    VID_UnlockBuffer ();

    D_EnableBackBufferAccess ();    // of all overlay stuff if drawing directly

    if (scr_drawdialog)
    {
        Sbar_Draw ();
        Draw_FadeScreen ();
        SCR_DrawNotifyString ();
        scr_copyeverything = true;
    }
    ...

    D_DisableBackBufferAccess ();   // for adapters that can't stay mapped in
                                    //  for linear writes all the time
    ...
}

If you dig deeper in the above, you will realize that:

D_DisableBackBufferAccess is an alias for VID_UnlockBuffer
D_EnableBackBufferAccess is an alias for VID_LockBuffer


I looked in code and found MGLDC *mgldc = NULL,*memdc = NULL but what is the difference between memdc and mgldc?

@black4 from the names, one would guess memdc is the device context for a regular in-memory back buffer, mgldc is one that’s supposed to go through an OpenGL pipeline.

@black4 memdc allows blitting from a memory buffer: https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/bf4ac424ce754894ac8f1dae6a3981954bc9852d/WinQuake/vid_win.c#L584
